# Detecting Rehashes or Collisions in Hashtable or Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, hashtable

I'm studying the .NET [Hashtable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379571%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class, and would like to experiment with various aspects...

- How many collisions (rehashes) are occurring in a given dataset
- Is the expansion of the hashtable safe for multithreaded access?
- What is the current load factor of my hashtable?

How can I experiment or learn the above information regarding a given hashtable or dictionary

Answer (score 2):

The thread safety of `Hashtable` is stated in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx). It is thread safe if only one thread writes to the `Hashtable`, and this has to include expansion.

Now, some digging using Reflector:

The load factor is stored in the `loadFactor` private field, which you can access using reflection if you want to check its value.

Rehashes are harder. These is no internal state of the `Hashtable` that is modified in a detectable way by a rehash *and only by a rehash*. Thus you would have to look at other options here, for example using Reflector to create your own identical Hashtable implementation and then adding some code to count rehashes. If you're doing that, you may as well expose the load factor as a property as well to make your life easier.

Comment: What else would modify the internal state other than a rehash?  If I observe my own interactions with the Hashtable, would that be sufficient to deduce whats happening?  ...I'll try using Reflector to answer this and will post the results here.

Comment: The link seems to indicate multiple writes are supported via Synchronized.

Comment: @makerofthings7, would You be so kind to post your findings here, please?